# UITableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath delegate method not called after programmatically selecting row

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom class (superclass `UITableViewController`).

I have an add button that:

1. Begins table updates.
2. Inserts row in table.
3. Ends table updates.
4. Calls `selectRowAtIndexPath`.
5. Calls `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Unfortunately, `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not being called after programatically selecting a row.

Note: Using Swift (not Objective-C).

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let indexPathZero: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    todoController.addNewTodoItem(nameOfItem: "test5")

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathZero], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
    self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 64
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

    // Ask user for input
    editCell(indexPathZero)
}

func editCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

**Solution**

```
let indexPathZero: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    todoController.addNewTodoItem(nameOfItem: "test5")

    let currSelectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

    if currSelectedIndexPath != nil {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(currSelectedIndexPath!, animated: true)
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: currSelectedIndexPath!)
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathZero], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
    self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 64
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

    // Ask user for input
    editCell(indexPathZero)
```

Comment: Can you include the code that's causing the issue?

Comment: Added code as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:). When you call `selectRowAtIndexPath`, it will not call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

"Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message, nor does it send `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers."

Comment: I figured it would be something along those lines. How to force the cells to be deselected then? I tried storing the last position selected. However, when I add a new cell to the top, the last position was 0 at the time, and the new cell is also now 0.

Comment: Then use the method deselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Got it working. Pretty obviously now that I think about it. In `addButton` I first get the currently selected index path. If it's not nil, I then proceed to deselect it and call the delegate method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. **Then**, I do my actual intended `addButton` method actions so that there is not "interference" between any previously selected rows and the new row.